# Access components of custom header view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header, headerfooter

A custom header class is created for the header, view using xib. Trying to get the value of UITextField from that header class. Below is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let customHeaderView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddHeaderTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! AddHeaderTableViewCell

customHeaderView.txtFieldAdd.placeholder = ""
return customHeaderView
}
```

When trying to get value from the textfields below:

```
 @objc func addMoreToMytask(sender: UIButton!) {

   isAddStep = false

    let header = tblAddedTasks.headerView(forSection: 0) as? AddHeaderTableViewCell
    let sectionTitle = header?.textLabel?.text

    arrAdded.append((header?.txtFieldAdd.text!)!)
    tblAddedTasks.reloadData()
}
```

It is giving error in this line

```
let header = tblAddedTasks.headerView(forSection: 0) as? AddHeaderTableViewCell
```

Gives warning and crash when run

```
Cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to unrelated type 'AddHeaderTableViewCell' always fails
```

Please guide for the same.

Comment: quick fix can be that don't cast to your AddHeaderTableViewCell, and access your textField using viewWithTag method.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the header object as a member.

```
var customHeaderView : AddHeaderTableViewCell = nil
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  customHeaderView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddHeaderTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! AddHeaderTableViewCell
  customHeaderView.txtFieldAdd.placeholder = ""
  return customHeaderView
}
```

And then you can use the member object;

```
@objc func addMoreToMytask(sender: UIButton!) {

    isAddStep = false

    // let header = tblAddedTasks.headerView(forSection: 0) as? AddHeaderTableViewCell
    // let sectionTitle = header?.textLabel?.text
    let sectionTitle = customHeaderView.textLabel?.text 

    arrAdded.append((customHeaderView.txtFieldAdd.text!)!)
    tblAddedTasks.reloadData()
}
```

I m not sure but the reason may optional value. 
Tableview only renders view on the screen, you may getting nil.
Signature of the function is;

```
func headerView(forSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView?
```

It returns an optional variable. 
You trying to cast an optional variable. 
XCode may not work perfectly on casting optional variables, so it can't warn you with enough info.

You may try;

```
tblAddedTasks.headerView(forSection: 0) as! AddHeaderTableViewCell
```

or

```
tblAddedTasks.headerView(forSection: 0)! as?  AddHeaderTableViewCell
```

Probably will crash but at least you will see the real reason for crashing.

Comment: It works, but it is not the solution to the question.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it and notify if it gets you off from your current crash.

Comment: If it works for you, please mark as the answer, so everyone will know the answer. Thanks.